# How to update all your drivers without paying

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod

Recently Blue Screen Of Death ( BSOD ) has been occurring on my computer and its because i have some drivers which needs updating.Each time my computer recover from it , I would get the message from Winzip prompting me to update all my drivers

[image]

Upon pressing the "Update all" button , i realised i needed to subscribe to the software before i could do so .

The [technical specification](http://www.dell.com/sg/p/alienware-m14x/pd) of my computer

[image]

**I need to know if theres any way to update all my driver without using Winzip , I do not wish to pay just to update my drivers.**

FYI : windows update does not solve the problem

Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4gbw2ekga5h7il1/uiwqufLNtF) which contains all my dump folders

Comment: share the dmp files (cloud service like Dropbox, OneDrive), so that we can see which driver is the cause.

Comment: I very much doubt your blue screens are due to your drivers needing to be updated.

Comment: @magicandre1981 what are dmp files and where could they be found

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am getting a  0xDEADDEAD: error , how do i find the cause ??

Comment: That could be caused by your wireless driver. I'd try upgrading that. Download it directly from Intel's web site.

Comment: the dump files are located here: **C:\Windows\Minidump** Copy the folder to your desktop, zip the folder and upload the Zip to a cloud service

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done I have already shared the link in the question via DropBox

Comment: Im surprised no one has said anything about the "driver updater"  usually those applications are scams

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you download drivers from alienware's site. http://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/alienware-m14x-r2.html

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is a bit of a pain.

You just have to visit the Website of the manufacturer of the single Components.

- Get the exact name of the Hardware e.g Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230
- Find the official product [website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+Wi-Fi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Centrino%C2%AE+Wireless-N+2230)
- Then download the matching driver for your Operating System
- Rinse and Repeat

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on `My Computer` > `Manage` > `Device Manager`
Choose the device or which you want to update driver then Right Click
Choose `Update Driver Software` after that  Choose `Search automatically for updated driver software` . If available then latest driver for your device will be installed automatically free of cost by `Microsoft`.

Answer (score 1):

ok, the Intel WIFI driver is the cause of this odd crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MANUALLY_INITIATED_CRASH1 (deaddead)
The user manually initiated this crash dump.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000f010012
Arg2: 000000000125025b
Arg3: 0000000012bc22ce
Arg4: 0000000068ec005e

Debugging Details:
------------------


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xDEADDEAD

PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
Netwsw00!tfdQueueMgrCheckForHang
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  Netwsw00.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xdeaddead_netwsw00!tfdqueuemgrcheckforhang+1c2


start             end                 module name
fffff880`08664000 fffff880`091a8000   Netwsw00 M (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\blue9600\Netwsw00.pdb\D36060AACCA8428B81D527C80BD122BA1\Netwsw00.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Netwsw00.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\Netwsw00.sys
    Image name: Netwsw00.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Feb 20 19:26:23 2012
```

[Download and install the latest ProSet/Wireless driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=Wireless%20ProSet) and look if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell/Alienware website can auto-detect what drivers you need to download, and if you haven't upgraded the machine, they already know what the hardware is inside of it based on your service tag. It's free, but it doesn't run automatically.

Go to http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/ca/en/04/Product/alienware-m14x-r2 for your machine (this is specific to your machine), enter your service tag, then click on the "Analyze System for Updates" button on the upper-left, next to the picture of the computer. It will the walk you through getting the correct drivers and installing them.

We have a handful of Dell machines at my work, and this is how I make sure I have the right drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using device doctor so when you click on a driver that needs an update it will automatically forward you to their website to download it. The only downside is that you are limited to only two driver downloads per day.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you to use 2 softwares - 'Driver Booster' and 'DriverMax'. Just download these 2 and install them and scan your computer. They will search for outdated drivers and shows you updates. You can download any update and install them successfully.

I personally use these 2 softwares. Out of the 2 'Driver Booster' is a free one and you can download any number of driver updates with it in one day. 'DriverMax' is also free, but you can only download 2 updates with it on 1 day. If you want to download more, upgrade to its Pro version.

So try these 2 and let me know about your experience.

Comment: Do not rely on those programs: just get the drivers from the manufacturer website.